# What's the smallest handheld or laptop that will drive a 4K Display Port (or HDMI 2.0) monitor at 60fps?

Tags: hdmi, display-port

Ideally I'm looking for a handheld, netbook, or 10-12" laptop.

It needs to be x86_64 (not ARM) with 8GB RAM or more.  The CPU needs to be faster than an Atom.

The screen has HDMI and Display Port inputs.

Comment: Are you just showing regular programs on it, or do you need 3D like video games,autocad, or etc?  Anything with significant amounts of 3d is going to require a full size graphics card.

Comment: Just for text editors and IDEs, no 3d or game support required.